# How to make more than 6 characters random alphanumeric by this code in trigger of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, random, triggers

I have a form for request registering by php and html.
I found a code to make 6 character random string for tracking code and should not be duplicate.this code is  in triggers for users table in mySql before inserting new row.

How can I make more than 6 characters random alphanumeric by this code in trigger of MySQL?

**And in your opinion is this code useful or is better than a code for random string in php??**

Whats your suggestion?

```
BEGIN
  declare ready int default 0;
  declare rnd_str text;

  while not ready DO set rnd_str := LOWER(lpad(conv(floor(rand()*pow(36,6)),10, 36), 6, 0));
     if not exists (select * from stu where st_trc = rnd_str)
     then
       set new.trck= rnd_str;
       set ready := 1;
     end if;
   end while;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a 12 character pseudorandom string is as easy as concatenating two six-character pseudorandom strings.

```
CONCAT(LOWER(lpad(conv(floor(rand()*pow(36,6)),10, 36), 6, 0)),
       LOWER(lpad(conv(floor(rand()*pow(36,6)),10, 36), 6, 0)))
```

I guess you can figure out how to generate 18 or 24 random characters. :-)

In terms of cryptographic security, neither this nor a php string generator based on `rand()` qualify: These are pseudorandom numbers, not real random numbers, and a stubborn attacker has an unfair advantage trying to guess them. MySQL doesn't have a way to generate cryptographically secure random numbers. PHP 7 does: http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php

(Cryptographically secure random numbers are numbers that are as hard as possible for an attacker to guess. Pseudorandom number generators use patterns, and true random numbers don't have any pattern. Therefore, pseudorandom numbers are easier to guess. What harm could it do to your business if a cybercriminal guessed one of your tracking codes? Only you know that. If guessing a tracking number can harm you, use more secure random numbers.)

In terms of convenience, generating these random strings either in php or MySQL is just fine. If the relevance of your random strings is short-lived (a week or two, for example) this approach will work sufficiently well.